# How to get Azure Functions's framework generated request id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions

Every time i am debugging my Azure Functions (locally) then invoking a function, the CLI (func.exe) always shows `requestId` as one of the incoming request's parameters which i am highly sure it is not from my side that generate it.

[image: screenshot from CLI]

My question is, is it possible to extract the value of `requestId` value from our code and how ? is this feature only specific for development/local debugging only ? since i can't find any documentation, article nor blog regarding this.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will find the request information in the `HttpContext`

```
req.HttpContext.Items["MS_AzureFunctionsRequestID"]
```

c# code example assuming you have the following signature

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log) {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have other two regarding this, can we reliably use this property even outside local/dev environment ? and, is there any docs regarding this property ? googling with such keyword only returns this StackOverflow question

Comment: Do you know what the v4 JS api equivalent to this is?

Comment: I'm seeing (v4 Functions, node.js) a `context.invocationId` that matches `customDimensions.InvocationId` in Application Insights